# Imprimir una columna de una matriz bidimensional en lenguaje C

Tags: c

El ejercicio consiste en crear una matriz de (5,5), y seleccionar 2 columnas para luego sumar todos los elementos de dichas columnas. Ya gracias a rand logré llenar la matriz con números aleatorios, pero no se me ocurre cómo imprimir columnas para poder seleccionar 2 de ellas (es decir, poder elegir qué columnas seleccionar) para después poder sumarlas. Por favor quedo muy atento para que me respondan, ya que el ejercicio lo tengo que resolver antes de que acabe el día. De antemano, muchas gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h> 

int main(){

int matriz[5][5], x, y;

    srand(time(0));

    for(x=0; x<5; x++)

    for(y=0; y<5; y++)

    matriz[x][y]=1+rand()%9;

  for(x=0; x<5; x++)

  {

    printf("\n");  

    for(y=0; y<5; y++)

    printf (" %d ", matriz[x][y]);

}

getch();

}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

int main(){

int matriz[5][5], x, y, sum;

    srand(time(0));

    for(x=0; x<5; x++)

    for(y=0; y<5; y++)

    matriz[x][y]=1+rand()%9;

  for(x=0; x<5; x++)

  {

    printf("\n");

    for(y=0; y<5; y++)

    printf (" %d ", matriz[x][y]);

}

printf("Que columna desea seleccionar?   ");

    scanf("%d", &y);

    if(y < 1 || y > 5)
    {
        printf("Error: La columna debe estar en el rango de 1 al 5");

        return 1;

    }

    --y;

    for(x=0; x<5; x++)

    {

        printf ("%d\n", matriz[x][y]);

        sum = sum + matriz[x][y];

    }

    printf("La suma de esa columna fue: %d\n", sum);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, necesitarás agregar en la pregunta, el código que tengas hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: Si fuiste capaz de rellenarla, fuiste capaz de llegar a cada una de las posiciones de la matriz, con lo que eres prefectamente capaz de recorrer elementos quedándote con los de la columna que te interese.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
int matriz[5][5], x, y;
    srand(time(0));
    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
    for(y=0; y<5; y++)
    matriz[x][y]=1+rand()%9;
  for(x=0; x<5; x++)
  {
    printf("\n");  
    for(y=0; y<5; y++)
    printf (" %d ", matriz[x][y]);
}
getch();
}

Comment: el problema es que llegué a cada una pero de forma aleatoria con rand, realmente desconozco cómo seleccionar una columna en específico

Comment: @NicolásLeón No agregues el código como comentario (se ve ilegible). Lo debes añadir en la pregunta.

Comment: ya aprendí cómo agregarlo a la pregunta, sorry

Comment: eso llevo hasta ahora, como dije antes, llegué sólo hasta el relleno de la matriz con números al azar, pero falta seleccionar 2 columnas cualquiera y sumar los elementos de dichas columnas seleccionadas, y mostrar como resultado final la suma mencionada anteriormente

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas pedir al usuario que ingrese las dos columnas que quiere seleccionar y posteriormente, ejecutas un bucle que vaya recorriendo cada fila con respecto a las columnas seleccionadas y de este modo, podremos sumar los elementos de ambas columnas.

En código quedaría de esta forma:

```
int main(void)
{
    int matriz[5][5], x, y;
    srand(time(0));

    int col1, col2;

    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
            matriz[x][y]=1+rand()%9;

    //Para imprimir la matriz original
    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        printf("\n");  
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
            printf (" %d ", matriz[x][y]);
    }

    //Para pedir la columna que desea seleccionar
    printf("Que columna desea seleccionar?");
    scanf("%d", &col1);

    printf("Que columna desea seleccionar?");
    scanf("%d", &col2);

    printf("El resultado de la suma de ambas columnas:\n");
    //Para realizar la suma de ambas columnas
    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
        printf("%d\n", matriz[x][col1] + matriz[x][col2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, se debe validar que el usuario solamente pueda ingresar una columna en el rango de `1` al `5` (porqué el tamaño de columnas de esa matriz es de `5`).

```
int main(void)
{
    int matriz[5][5], x, y;
    srand(time(0));

    int suma = 0, col1, col2;

    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
            matriz[x][y]=1+rand()%9;

    //Para imprimir la matriz original
    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        printf("\n");  
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
            printf (" %d ", matriz[x][y]);
    }

    //Para pedir la columna que desea seleccionar y lo guardamos en el vector
    printf("Que columna desea seleccionar?");
    scanf("%d", &col1);

    printf("Que columna desea seleccionar?");
    scanf("%d", &col2);

    if((col1 < 1 || col1 > 5) || ((col2 < 1 || col2 > 5) ))
    {
        printf("Error: Las columnas deben estar en el rango de 1 al 5");
        return 1;
    }

    /*
        Hay que decrementar ambas variables, debido a que, 
        las columnas se empieza a contar desde 0 a N-1 (N es el tamaño de columnas)
    */
    --col1;
    --col2;

    printf("El resultado de la suma de ambas columnas:\n");
    //Para realizar la suma de ambas columnas
    for(x=0; x<5; x++)
        printf("%d\n", matriz[x][col1] + matriz[x][col2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: mi error, el resultado final debe mostrar la matriz entera, luego debe preguntar qué columnas desea sumar para finalmente mostrar el resultado de esa suma. Hay que sumar 2 columnas distintas. Intenté agregar tu propuesta de solución a la mía pero me arroja resultados ilógicos, números altos que generalmente son algo parecido a, ejemplo, 32235, de inmediato subo el nuevo progreso para que revises

Comment: justo debajo del codigo actual puse el propuesto

Comment: @NicolásLeón Por favor no edites la respuesta del usuario que te ayuda con contenido que cambia su estructura, si tienes otra solución eres mas que bienvenido a publicarla

Comment: lo siento! soy nuevo en esta plataforma ):

Comment: @NicolásLeón He editado mi respuesta, espero que te sirva!